# Suggestion for reducing the bloat of an asp.net menu

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have an asp.net (3.5) app whose pages are mostly lightweight except for the bloat of the aspnet menu which accounts for about 1/3 of the data transferred from the server.

This menu appears on every page (by the use of a master page) and is transmitted over and over slowing everything down.

How can I improve this situation?

I had some ideas but I don’t know enough about them to know if doing them would be a good idea or how I would code them.

If you give me a suggestion could you also send me a link that explains how to implement the solution?

The menu is hardcoded as of now, but will probably be read from a db at some point.

How could it be loaded once and then used by each web page rather than sending the rendering html over the wire each time?

Comment: How many total items? Whats the size? How many levels? Average items per level?

Comment: @nunespascal 7 in the top level, 6 have sublevels with a total of with about 17 choices in the 1st sublevel, and about 2 each options in two 2nd level.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very huge menu. Seems like you are over optimizing. Are you facing any performance issues? The root cause may be something else.

Comment: Yes, i am looking for ways to improve performance. This small meni is being rendered with 25,000 html characters. There is not much going on on most pages. For example, the view state on one page is 5500 chars.

Comment: Could you post the code to jsfiddle so we can see - might be you just need to refactor the html/css/javascript or use a well written plugin. Loading sub menu items with ajax is a possibility once it data driven too